# The comparison sets after grouping dataframe (Python 3, pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using Python 3 and pandas. There are two dataframe.

For example, the first:

```
     Key  Sample
0    A    Sa
1    B    Sb
2    A    Sc
...  ...  ...
```

The second:

```
     Key  Sample
0    A    Se
1    A    Sa
2    B    Sg
...  ...  ...
```

how to use the pandas library to generate the following table:

```
     Key  Rate_first  Rate_second
0    A    1.00        0.92
1    B    1.00        1.00
2    С    0.95        0.60
...  ...  ...         ...
```

where Rate_first (for key == 'A') = #unique samples with key == 'A' from **first dataframe** / #union(samples with key == 'A' from first dataframe and second dataframe).

Rate_second – similar.

P.S.: Guess need to use the groupby function, but because of lack of experience, do not understand how to apply it to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion, this is also fairly easy to do. Try this:

```
In []: df_merged = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
       df_total = pd.concat([df1.groupby('key')['Sample'].count(),
                             df2.groupby('key')['Sample'].count(),
                             df_merged.groupby('key')['Sample'].unique().apply(len)],
                             axis=1, ignore_index=True)
       df_total.columns = ['Sample1_Count', 'Sample2_Count', 'Union_Count']
       df_total
Out[]:      Sample1_Count  Sample2_Count Union_Count
       key
       A    4              3             4
       B    1              1             1

In []: df_total['Rate_first'] = df_total['Sample1_Count']/df_total['Union_Count']
       df_total['Rate_second'] = df_total['Sample2_Count']/df_total['Union_Count']
       df_total
Out[]:      Sample1_Count  Sample2_Count Union_Count  Rate_first  Rate_second
       key
       A    4              3             4            1.0         0.75
       B    1              1             1            1.0         1.0
```

---

---

**Old answer below**

If I understand correctly, you want to compute the share of each DataFrame to the total. Try this:

```
In []: df_total = pd.merge(df1.groupby('key')['Sample'].count(),
                            df2.groupby('key')['Sample'].count(),
                            suffixes=('_1', '_2'))
       df_total
Out[]:       Sample_1  Sample_2
        key
        A    2         2
        B    1         1

In []: df_total['Rate_first'] = df_total['Sample_1']/(df_total['Sample_1'] + df_total['Sample_2'])
       df_total['Rate_second'] = df_total['Sample_2']/(df_total['Sample_1'] + df_total['Sample_2'])
       df_total
Out[]:       Sample_1  Sample_2  Rate_first  Rate_second
        key
        A    2         2         0.5         0.5
        B    1         1         0.5         0.5
```

If this is not what you are looking for, you need to better frame your question. I tried the best with what I understood from your question.

Comment: Kartik, thanks for the quick reply. This is almost what I need.

I will try to explain with an example. For example, in the first dataframe samples with key == 'A' is following: Sa, Sb, Sc, Sd;
And in the second dataframe: Sa, Sb, Sd;

Then

#unique samples with key == 'A' from first dataframe == 4
#unique samples with key == 'A' from second dataframe == 3
#union(samples with key == 'A' from first dataframe and second dataframe) == 4

Rate_first == 4/4 == 1.00
Rate_second == 3/4 == 0.75

Comment: Hang on a second! How is `union(samples with key == 'A' from first dataframe and second dataframe) = 4`? Do you mean `max(samples with key == 'A' from first dataframe and second dataframe)`?

Comment: I use ["union"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) from set theory.

Union([A, B, C], [D, C]) == [A, B, C, D]

Comment: Oh yeah! Sorry, I'm too sleepy. Wait a few minutes, I almost have an answer.